# iptables - use ubuntu as router

Tags: networking, server, iptables

I have an ubuntu PC which I would like to use as "general server" (I don't know a good name for the purpose, let me try to explain).

I have several other devices in my network, bunch of raspberry pi's and some other IoT devices, accessible through my local network.

I want to be able to browse to 1 PC, my ubuntu PC, and depending on port numbers forward the traffic to the device I specify. For example, port http://myubuntubox:1234/ will NAT the packets to a raspberry pi on port 8080.

I try to achieve this using ip tables but I'm getting nowhere (learned a lot already though! :)).

- ubuntu: 192.168.1.102
- rpi: 192.168.1.12, which hosts a webserver on port 8080

nat/prerouting:

```
sudo iptables -t nat --insert PREROUTING 1 -p tcp -d 192.168.1.102 --dport 1234 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.12:8080
```

filter/forward:

```
sudo iptables -t filter --insert FORWARD 1 -p tcp -d 192.168.1.102 --dport 1234 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

nat/postrouting:

```
sudo iptables -t nat --append POSTROUTING -p tcp -j MASQUERADE
```

I thought this would allow me to access my ubuntubox in a webbrowser as follows:

```
http://192.168.1.102:1234
```

and that it would then simply navigate/forward to my raspberry pi on port 8080. But unfortunately it times out.

What is it that I am doing wrong?

PS: I am intentionally inserting the DNAT and FORWARD rules on position 1 so that they are the first ones in  the chain to prevent the "existing" chain to reject/drop the rule before it gets to mine.

```
bp@bp-ubuntu:~$ sudo iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Fri Mar 25 22:49:53 2022
*filter
:INPUT DROP [141095:62750359]
:FORWARD DROP [592:31344]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [42:3693]
:ufw-after-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-after-input - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-after-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-before-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-output - [0:0]
:ufw-logging-allow - [0:0]
:ufw-logging-deny - [0:0]
:ufw-not-local - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-input - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-output - [0:0]
:ufw-skip-to-policy-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-skip-to-policy-input - [0:0]
:ufw-skip-to-policy-output - [0:0]
:ufw-track-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-track-input - [0:0]
:ufw-track-output - [0:0]
:ufw-user-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-user-input - [0:0]
:ufw-user-limit - [0:0]
:ufw-user-limit-accept - [0:0]
:ufw-user-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-user-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-user-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-user-output - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-reject-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-track-input
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.1.102/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1234 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-reject-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-track-forward
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-reject-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-track-output
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 137 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 138 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 139 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 445 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-logging-forward -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-after-logging-input -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-before-forward -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 12 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -j ufw-user-forward
-A ufw-before-input -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 12 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p udp -m udp --sport 67 --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-not-local
-A ufw-before-input -d 224.0.0.251/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -d 239.255.255.250/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 1900 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-user-input
-A ufw-before-output -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -j ufw-user-output
-A ufw-logging-allow -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "
-A ufw-logging-deny -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j RETURN
-A ufw-logging-deny -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type MULTICAST -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-not-local -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-forward -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-input -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-output -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-track-output -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-track-output -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5903 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m udp --dport 5903 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5901 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m udp --dport 5901 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5902 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m udp --dport 5902 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-limit -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
-A ufw-user-limit -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A ufw-user-limit-accept -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Mar 25 22:49:53 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Fri Mar 25 22:49:53 2022
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.102/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1234 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.12:8080
-A POSTROUTING -o enxe8ea6a7effac -p tcp -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.102
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Mar 25 22:49:53 2022
```

Comment: Did you enable forwarding `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` ?

Comment: @Virsacer yes I did.

Comment: my first question is can you run `sudo iptables-save` and take all the output from it and put it into your question as an edit with code formatting?  You indicate specific rules here, but it doesn't give us the full overview of what you're attempting to do here so it would be better to see *all* your rules that're in play not just these specific rules (PLUS the default policies in place in your setup).

Comment: @ThomasWard updated question. If I need to share more please let me know.

Comment: if you want to use Ubuntu as a router, don't use `ufw` simultaneously.  Your UFW firewall sets the default INPUT ruleset to DROP which means the traffic NOT permitted inbound in your UFW rules that match the NAT rules won't work, and I don't see matching INPUT rules in your output that would match the NAT rules.  (INPUT and NAT go hand in hand).  I would suggest you go straight `iptables` and NOT mix and match ufw+iptables if you intend to do advanced NAT and use Ubuntu with iptables as a router.

Comment: Start by doing `sudo ufw disable` and then add your rules.  This is the first step to test your NAT.

Comment: @ThomasWard Thx so much! That did the trick. Finally got it working :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135056/discussion-between-thomas-ward-and-bas).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of your current setup, you are mixing UFW and advanced NAT rules.

UFW was not built to operate as a full scale firewall on a router, and runs in default DROP mode for all incoming traffic.

If your system is going to behave as a router you will need to set up proper INPUT, OUTPUT, FORWARD, PREROUTING, and POSTROUTING rules for all traffic in and out of your network.  But you'll have to run `sudo ufw disable` FIRST which will change the default 'DROP' policies to 'ACCEPT'.  Then reharden your box from there with the proper `iptables` rules to match.  You will also need to set up proper INPUT and OUTPUT rules for traffic coming into the router and leaving the router regardless of network interface.

Setting up those rules is a bit beyond the scope of the question being asked.  However, I'm happy to work to try and get you set up with a default ruleset that will protect you from outside threats but work like a standard off the shelf network router and pass your traffic to the Internet without blocks and let related traffic come back in.

Comment: Thx again Thomas! Life saver